# Class referenced in the manifest, was not found in the project or libraries

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I wonder why in the manifest it has error at the com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity although I've put the dependencies and repositories correctly. What went wrong?

```
<activity
            android:name="*com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity*"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```

Comment: It seems that the stackoverflow authorities removed some comments below. I still think it would be useful for you to look at the routines for [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), especially since you are new at this forum. Both you and the answerer get reputations for this.

Answer (score 2):

The path preceding the class name `UCropActivity` is *the package*. The package is defined in the class, at the top, and in the manifest, also at the top. If it is the same package, you don't need to include it in the class name in the manifest; you can enter just the class name **preceded by a period**: `.UCropActivity`.

It is *no error* to include the package in the activity name, but **no asterisks should be used**. Thus, the expression
`android:name="*com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity*"`
is invalid.

If you have different packages in the class and the manifest, the package must be included in the activity name.

Answer (score 1):

```
<activity
        android:name=".UCropActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.